# Ruby on Rails Save Data into model in two ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model

I want to duplicate wordpress post functionality.

For example you can create new post and save in two ways - "Publish Post" and "Make Draft"

Using Rails resources routes I created `create` method and `new` method.

Also I created custom methods to save in publish mode and draft mode.

```
class GroupEventsController < ApplicationController
def new
  @ge = GroupEvent.new
end

def publishnew
  @ge = GroupEvent.new(groupevent_params)
  @ge.save
  redirect_to @ge
end
def create
  @ge = GroupEvent.new(groupevent_params)
  @ge.save
  redirect_to @ge
end

private
def groupevent_params   
  abort params.inspect          
  params.require(:group_event).permit(:name, :description, :startdate, :duration, :status)
end
```

It works perfect when submit form but when you go to publishnew method it is not working. 
It shows such error. *param is missing or the value is empty: group_event*

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to add to your question (by editing your question, not by posting to comments) the output in your console. I believe you will find that you do not have `group_event` in your parameters. Also, if you're going to be doing Rails for a while, it wouldn't hurt to follow naming conventions (especially since that was your challenge on your last question).

Comment: How are you making it post to the `publishnew` action? JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a different approach to get the same behavior.

If I understand correct, you want to have form submission that will behave differently.

How about add two buttons...

```
f.submit :publish
f.submit :draft
```

This will have some thing like

```
<input type="submit" value="publish" id=".." name="commit" />
<input type="submit" value="draft" id=".." name="commit" />
```

Then in the controller action you can do some thing like

```
class GroupsEventsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if params[:commit] == 'publish'
      publish_event
    else
      draft_event
    end
  end

  private

  def publish_event
    // Appropriate code here
  end

  def draft_event
    // Appropriate code here
  end
end
```

That way you don't need to do JS foo doo in the client side to get it to post to different routes.